# Qt 5.x в QWebView кривой шрифт Arial

Tags: qt5, шрифты

Добрый день!

Что-то странное у меня творится со шрифтами Arial в QWebView, такое впечатление, что он его (шрифт) не видит, хотя шрифты на месте. (Скриншоты)

Происходит такое только в Linux (Gentoo + KDE 4.14.3) и только в Qt 5.x. В Qt 4.x, а так же в винде и в маке все прекрасно.

Код совершенно стандартный, ошибиться там точно негде. :)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView(this);
    view->setGeometry(0 ,0, this->width(), this->height());
    view->load(QUrl("http://google.ru"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Я, если честно, уже и мозг и гугл сломал, не выходит каменный цветок...

Есть у кого-нибудь идеи, куда копать?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, видимо, я один такой везучий. ;)

В общем, пока обошелся костылём.

```
QWebSettings *settings = view->settings();
settings->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl("qrc:/fonts/fonts_fix.css"));
```

Ну и в самой css-ке, подгружаю нужные шрифты из ресурсов:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family : Arial; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style : normal; 
    src : url("qrc:/fonts/arial.ttf"); 
} 
@font-face { 
    font-family : Arial; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-style : normal; 
    src : url("qrc:/fonts/arialbd.ttf"); 
}
```

Мало ли, вдруг кому пригодится.